# The average amount of time required to travel between two points in a torus-like space

Tags: c++, performance, rcpp

I have recently started to work with C++ and I do consider myself quite basic in C++ coding.

I have made the following two functions and I was wondering whether someone could give me some hints on how to improve and speed up this code.

Please, note that the second function is then used in `R` through `Rcpp R` package.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

double sumAll(double i, double j, int a, int b, double coeff) {

  double pi = 2 * acos(0.0);

  double total = 0;
  int half_a =  a / 2;
  int half_b =  b / 2;

  for (int k = 0; k <= half_a; ++k) {

    for (int l = 0; l <= half_b; ++l) {

      double fkl;
      if (k == 0 && l == 0) {
        fkl = 0;
      } else {
        fkl = pow((1 - (coeff * (1 - cos(2.0 * pi * k / a)))), 2.0) *
              pow((1 - (coeff * (1 - cos(2.0 * pi * l / b)))), 2.0);
      }

      double a1 = 1 - (cos(2.0 * pi * i * k / a) * cos(2.0 * pi * j * l / b));

      double deltaa;
      if (k == 0) {
        deltaa = 1;
      } else {
        deltaa = 0.5;
      }

      double deltab;
      if (l == 0) {
        deltab = 1;
      } else {
        deltab = 0.5;
      }

      if (k == 0 && l == 0) {

        total = total + 0;

      } else {

        double res = (fkl * a1) / (deltaa * deltab * (1 - fkl));

        total = total + res;
      }
    }
  }
  return total;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector series_Sum(NumericVector xvec, NumericVector yvec, int a, int b,
                         double coeff) {

  int size = xvec.length();
  NumericVector series_res(size);

  for (double i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    series_res[i] = sumAll(xvec[i], yvec[i], a, b, coeff);
  }

  return series_res;
}
```

Consider that in `sumAll` :

- i and j: are integers, which can get values between 0 and a/2 or 0 and b/2, respectively.
- coeff: can be a value between 0 and 1.0.
- a and b: can be any integer values higher than 5 (arbitrary choice).

In `series_Sum` :

- xvec and yvec: are vectors of i and j values.

In other words, `series_Sum` use `sumAll` over several possible combinations of i and j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write `using namespace std;`.

The constants including `pi` are provided in a standard header already.  If you did need to define a constant,  use `constexpr`.

```
double deltaa;
if (k == 0) {
        deltaa = 1;
      } else {
        deltaa = 0.5;
      }
```

That is much clear to write as:

```
const double deltaa = k==0 ? 1 : 0.5;
```

which also allows you to initialize the value in the declaration and make it `const`.

The block for `deltaa` and `deltab` are the same except for the parameter.  You should make a small inline function for that.

```
total = total + 0;
```

Why?

```
total = total + res;
```

Better to write `total += res;`

---

Generally:

Use `const` where you can.  Initialize variables in the statement where you declare them.

In addition to using `const`, which may allow the optimizer to better figure such things out on its own, consider hoisting subexpressions out of the loop.  For example `pi * k` does not change inside the nested loop so compute it once in the outer loop only.

Express your comments as preconditions (e.g. `assert` or [`Expect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54521085/how-to-use-c-expects-operator) statements).

---

```
for (double i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    series_res[i] = sumSij(half_a, half_b, xvec[i], yvec[i], a, b, coeff);
  }
```

Why is `i` of type `double`?  It's an index into the `NumericArray`s.

I see a call to `sumSij` but no call to `sumAll`.  The code is not complete, and doesn't agree with your comment (unless the former calls the latter, but I don't know how).

Comment: Yes, sorry. There was a typographical error when I copied my code here. The correct function is `sumAll`.

Comment: Technically the edit by OP invalidates part of your answer. I'll leave it up to you if you want to edit that part out, since the code wasn't working during your review. Non-working code is cause to close a question, not cause to answer it.

Comment: @Mast the two functions had different number of parameters, so I ruled out simply naming it wrong.  Re "non working" I don't know what's in the Rcpp header file.

Comment: @CafféSospeso can't be:  the number of parameters doesn't match.  The function defined takes 5, the call at the bottom of the listing passes 7.

Comment: Once again, you were right. I just edited. Now it should be correct.

Comment: I have a small comment/question. How `Expects` operator can be used, exactly? For instance, in my code. I looked around but it is not very clear to me.

Comment: @CafféSospeso same as the old `assert`.  Comment is _"coeff: can be a value between 0 and 1.0."_  Expressed as code, `Expects(coeff>=0.0 && coeff<=1.0);`.  Note that I had to decide whether you meant `>` or `>=` because the English was not rigorous.  The code is more exact.  (P.S. it's not an operator)

Comment: Ok, then it is a rigorous way within the code to make sure that, for the example you made, coeff is higher or equal to 0 AND lower or equal to 1. Otherwise the code exits. Thanks for the clarification.